# fetching multiple vales and keys from dict

Tags: python

```
movies={
'actors':{'prabhas':{'knownAs':'Darling', 'awards':{'nandi':1, 'cinemaa':1, 'siima':1},'remuneration':100, 'hits':{'industry':2, 'super':3,'flops':8}, 'age':41, 'height':6.1, 'mStatus':'single','sRate':'35%'}, 
  'pavan':{'knownAs':'Power Star', 'awards':{'nandi':2, 'cinemaa':2, 'siima':5}, 'hits':{'industry':2,  'super':7,'flops':16}, 'age':48, 'height':5.9, 'mStatus':'married','sRate':'37%','remuneration':50}, 
 }, 
 'actress':{ 
'tamanna':{'knownAs':'Milky Beauty', 'awards':{'nandi':0, 'cinemaa':1, 'siima':1}, 'remuneration':10, 'hits':{'industry':1, 'super':7,'flops':11}, 'age':28, 'height':5.9, 'mStatus':'single', 'sRate':'40%'}, 
 'rashmika':{'knownAs':'Butter Milky Beauty', 'awards':{'nandi':0, 'cinemaa':0, 'siima':2},  'remuneration':12,'hits':{'industry':0, 'super':4,'flops':2}, 'age':36, 'height':5.9, 'mStatus':'single', 'sRate':'30%'},
```

1.What are the total number of Nandi Awards won by actors?
2. What is the success rate of Prince? 
3.What is the name of Prince?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Please format code snippet properly.  1) use code blocks; 2) pretty-format `movies` for readability.

Comment: am a new learner,@DmitriyNeledva

Comment: me too, what have you tied?

Comment: not showing any error  in ques while i pressed run@KlasŠ.

Comment: f0r 3. i tried ----print(movies.get('prince'))@DmitriyNeledva

Comment: `movies.get('prince')` looks for key `prince` inside of `movies` dict but there is no such key so it returns None

Comment: movies={
'actors':{'mahesh':{'knownAs':'Prince','awards':{'nandi':8, 'cinemaa':3, 'siima':3},'remuneration':50, 'hits':{'industry':2, 'super':6,'flops':11},'age':46, 'height':6.2, 'mStatus':'married','sRate':'46%'}}
@DmitriyNeledva

Comment: look at your initial question, there is no Mahesh in data you've provided

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can answer the first question with this:

```
import jmespath 

movies={
    "actors": {
        "prabhas": {
            "knownAs": "Darling",
            "awards": {
                "nandi": 1,
                "cinemaa": 1,
                "siima": 1
            },
            "remuneration": 100,
            "hits": {
                "industry": 2,
                "super": 3,
                "flops": 8
            },
            "age": 41,
            "height": 6.1,
            "mStatus": "single",
            "sRate": "35%"
        },
        "pavan": {
            "knownAs": "Power Star",
            "awards": {
                "nandi": 2,
                "cinemaa": 2,
                "siima": 5
            },
            "hits": {
                "industry": 2,
                "super": 7,
                "flops": 16
            },
            "age": 48,
            "height": 5.9,
            "mStatus": "married",
            "sRate": "37%",
            "remuneration": 50
        }
    },
    "actress": {
        "tamanna": {
            "knownAs": "Milky Beauty",
            "awards": {
                "nandi": 0,
                "cinemaa": 1,
                "siima": 1
            },
            "remuneration": 10,
            "hits": {
                "industry": 1,
                "super": 7,
                "flops": 11
            },
            "age": 28,
            "height": 5.9,
            "mStatus": "single",
            "sRate": "40%"
        },
        "rashmika": {
            "knownAs": "Butter Milky Beauty",
            "awards": {
                "nandi": 0,
                "cinemaa": 0,
                "siima": 2
            },
            "remuneration": 12,
            "hits": {
                "industry": 0,
                "super": 4,
                "flops": 2
            },
            "age": 36,
            "height": 5.9,
            "mStatus": "single",
            "sRate": "30%"
        }
    }
}

total_nandies_by_actors = sum(jmespath.search('[]',jmespath.search('actors.*.*.nandi',movies)))
```

but there is no `Prince` in the data you've provided